# How to draw partial classes on a UML diagram?

Tags: c#, uml, partial-classes

I would like to know how to indicate in a UML Class Diagram that 2 classes are partial.

For example:

File 'ClassApart1.cs'

```
partial class ClassA{ /* this class is used for constructors and methods */ }
```

File 'ClassApart2.cs'

```
partial class ClassA{ /* this class is used for properties */ }
```

Is there any convention to indicate/draw my situation in UML?

Comment: Why do you want to show them as separately in UML, partial classes are  infact a single class

Comment: Why should it *matter* from the point of view of UML that a class is broken out into multiple files?  It seems like an unimportant implementation detail.

Comment: If you give the class different names, they are no more partial classes. They are two different classes.

Comment: If you've got this big of a class, I feel like you have other issues.

Comment: I'm new in UML environment... In my opinion could be interesting to show a deep/detailed description of the classes composing my project. I know that the compiler will see them like a single class but my goal is to show the whole project composition.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just have three boxes connected by lines   SomeClass PartOne PartTwo

This image is from ibm:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I am pretty sure that it does not exist any IUML formal convention for that.
In fact each tool (C# generator) will bring it own convention.
Servy depicted into his answer the "IBM convention". 
Modelio, for example, uses a dedicated properties...

[image]